# How to get differences between two dictionaries based on list values?

Tags: python, dictionary, comparison, difference

Assume you have tow dictionary A and B:

```
A = {'a':[5, 3], 't':[4], 'd':[2, 5, 6]}
B = {'s':[11,5], 'a':[4,6], 'd':[0, 6, 3]}
```

How can you get differences between A and B values in new dictionary? 
Difference meaning A - B => for example for 'a' key is  [5, 3] - [4,6] result is [1, -3]

Comment: Define "difference". Is it wrt A or wrt B? Also, the keys aren't even the same between the two.

Comment: keys difference you want? or value dif?

Comment: I think an example of your desired result is needed.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean `A - B` and only on `key`s that exist in both. These are a lot of assumptions but your question is a bit vague..

How about this:

```
A = {'a':[5, 3], 't':[4], 'd':[2, 5, 6]}
B = {'s':[11,5], 'a':[4,6], 'd':[0, 3]}

C = {k: [x - y for x, y in zip(v, B[k])] for k, v in A.items() if k in B}
print(C)  # {'d': [2, 2], 'a': [1, -3]}
```

If you do not care whether the `key`s exist in both and want to simply "subtract" `B` go with `.get()` and [`zip_longest` from `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) with a default parameter of `0` like so:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
C = {k: [x - y for x, y in zip_longest(v, B.get(k, []), fillvalue=0)] for k, v in A.items()}
print(C)  # {'a': [1, -3], 'd': [2, 2, 6], 't': [4]}
```

Comment: Should've waited for a clarification from OP before posting, this question deserves to be closed as it is.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ You are right, I regretted posting this. Should I delete?

Comment: Mm, it's not really my place to say, though I would suggest you did so (save yourself from any dv'ers), and then undelete once OP clarifies you've done what they want...

Comment: Hi @ Ev. Kounis, Thanks for your help. Sorry my weak explain for question.

Comment: Hi @ cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thanks for your guide.

Answer (score 1):

How about this? it adds any values in B missing from A and if the key is not missing it subtracts the sum of the value in B from the sum of the value in A:

```
A = {'a':[5, 3], 't':[4], 'd':[2, 5, 6]}
B = {'s':[11,5], 'a':[4,6], 'd':[0, 3]}

def merge_and_differences(d1,d2):
    d3 = d1.copy()
    for k,v in d2.items():
        if k not in d3:
            d3[k] = v
        else:
            d3[k] = sum(d3[k]) - sum(d2[k])
    return d3

C = merge_and_differences(A,B)

print (C)
```

results:

```
{'a': -2, 's': [11, 5], 't': [4], 'd': 10}
```